# Replace words/phrases in existing PDF or docx with other words

Tags: pdf, .net-core, pdf-generation, libreoffice, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to make a dynamic PDF generator as an .NET Core API. I want to take an existing PDF, or .docx file, and edit it so it replaces the current name (John Doe) with something that can be replaced like `#NAME_PLACEHOLDER`.

I then want to transform `#NAME_PLACEHOLDER -> John Doe` (or whatever is in the `KeyValuePair` or `Dictionary<string, string>`).

I am running this on a Docker environment, so I can easily execute commands and I am willing to do that as well.

So far I have tried a few things:

- ***1) pdf2htmlEX***

  - Executes as `pdf2htmlEX file.pdf`
  - Does the job pretty well
  - Can be converted back to PDF using Google Chrome headless or similar
  - **Problem: Only the characters used in the PDF can be used to replace. So if I only use `A, B, C` as characters, it will make `D` into Times New Roman (or default font)**
- ***2) LibreOffice ODT to PDF***

  - This was pretty nice, because  I could simply unzip the .odt file, open content.xml, search and replace, then save it as an .odt file again
  - Could be converted into PDF rather easily using `soffice --convert-to pdf`
  - LibreOffice is quite nice
  - **Problem 1: Microsoft Word -> Save as ODT tends to break the formatting, so we have to use LibreOffice to go and change it back again**
  - **Problem 2: We don't want to move away from Microsoft's Office suite**
- ***3) HTML to PDF using Chrome Headless***

  - What you see is what you get
  - By far the best option, if we're all developers aaand have unlimited time
  - **Problem 1: Only our developers can make changes, since our marketing department do not know HTML**
  - **Problem 2: Our existing PDFs would have to be rewritten in HTML**

As you can see, I have tried a bunch of things. None of them, except Chrome Headless, has lived up to my expectations. What I really like about #3 is *what you see is what you get*. I can make the whole thing in HTML, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and see what it looks like as a finished PDF, basically.

I am looking for a better solution, though. It can be paid. It can be free. All I need is to change out words/phrases with other words dynamically, which apparently seems like a tough thing to do.

Comment: "All I need is ... which apparently seems like a tough thing to do" pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @usr2564301 Except I can do this whole thing easily, if I could find a good docx to PDF converter. Then I can simply edit the content of the docx file (unzip and zip it again), then convert it to PDF. Only problem is: The paid options are literally $1000+ per month, as it seems. I'm willing to buy a lifetime license, but not this $1000+ per month bullcrap.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for specifying what you've already found clearly.  It helps a lot providing a succinct answer.

The conversion is always tricky - I'm sure you *know* Word has trouble displaying/editing some Word documents itself.

I have experience regarding point #2 "LibreOffice ODT to PDF" and can suggest a few things to test:

1. Don't use Microsoft to do the docx->odt conversion.  It's not good as you know.  Use LibreOffice itself to do this step.  The rest of your process remains the same.
2. For some documents, Libre Office does doc->odt much better.  So, you can instead work with DOC format and get a better result without any other changes.
3. You won't be able to remove the devs from the process, but you can certainly *reduce* their role allowing your business/marketing teams to have more direct input simply by:

   - get the starting point document to the devs to run through the conversion process.  The devs can "clean up" the document to make it convert nicely.
   - make this version of the document the "official" starting point.  The business or technical teams can load it, adjust it, and put it back into the process.
   - if possible, expose a test-platform to the business teams so they can download, adjust, upload and render to PDF.  This cycle means they will be able to achieve more and if they're good, do impressive stuff without any dev input.
   - the above steps simply mean don't expect perfect conversion of arbitrary complex documents.  Starting from a (even complex) working baseline is great.

Some of that might show you that your #2 is actually going to get the best overall results.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! One of the problems with using LibreOffice is, the business team does not want to move away from Word. If we all used LibreOffice, this would be a no-brainer. Would you say this is better: 1) Make the document in Word and save as docx. 2) Use soffice command to convert docx to odt. 3) Edit the odt file and save it (all programmably). 4) Convert odt to pdf using soffice command. Our alternative right now is Acrobat + PDF Form Inputs, but for each iteration of the document, we need to edit the original document and insert all the inputs again. Tedious process.

Comment: You're welcome.  Certainly it's clear your team should stick with MS Office if that's what they are used to.  So "yes" is my answer to your question.  Business / dev always work with an MS Office document and your application uses Libre Office to take it through to a PDF.  You can do the programmatic manipulation at DOCX or ODT stage - whatever suits your environment.  Just remember the first point under my answer 3. above - get the dev team (yourself) to create the first baseline of the DocX since you know it will convert well via Libre Office.

Comment: So I tried using `soffice` to convert my docx -> odt -> pdf. It did work and it looks decent, but it failed doing two things: Right align text in the header (using `TAB` to tab between the left, center, and right) and it placed one of the images in a table in the center instead of to the right (3 columns and the center columns was empty, but now it has an image). However, it does the image bug when I simply open the docx in LibreOffice's desktop application as well.

Comment: The conversions are not 100% for all possible layouts, but most problems can be managed with small changes to the document.  Once you've done that you have your good baseline version.